# Recaptcha image missing if using browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, browser-cache, page-refresh

I am using PHP to create the page. Now my problem is force reloading a page when using browser back button, the recaptcha image is missing.

I use this code, but didn't work:

```html
var perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

if (perfEntries[0].type === "back_forward") {
    location.reload(true);
}
```

Below is the result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeIOc.png)

This is video to show how I get the error link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/13vaAf5X7P5RFrQZ9OPD7dDRfCne3QFVL/view?usp=sharing

I have also add this code in the body, but also didn't work:

```html
body onLoad="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()"
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve the problem. Thanks.